# pandas dataframe split value into 3 and two-two combine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

sorry for my title, I'm not sure how to describe my problem, so i'll just show what i want to do with my dataframe.

right now I'm having a dataframe similar to this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': '(apple, 2), (banana, 3), (orange, 4)', 'B':1},
                   index=[0])
```

```
                                      A  B
0  (apple, 2), (banana, 3), (orange, 4)  1
```

and I want to get a dataframe like this below

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':['(apple, banana)', '(apple, orange)', '(banana, orange)'],
              'B':[1,1,1]},
              index=[0,1,2])
```

```
                  A  B
0   (apple, banana)  1
1   (apple, orange)  1
2  (banana, orange)  1
```

as you can see, the length changed during the transform, Is there any easy way so I can get the result ? thanks a lot

Comment: where did "banana" come from in the first row of the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) your string, and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the column:

```
(df1.assign(A=df1['A'].str.split('(?<=\)),\s+'))
    .explode('A', ignore_index=True)
)
```

output:

```
             A  B
0   (apple, 2)  1
1  (banana, 3)  1
2  (orange, 4)  1
```

regex:

```
(?<=\))   # if preceded by a closing parenthesis
,\s+      # match a comma + at least one space as separator
```